# How can i delete lines from a text file only if the previous line contains a certain phrase

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to delete lines from a text file via powershell only if the previous line contains a certain phrase

Very new to powershell so haven't tried many things yet.
I have got to the point where i am able to delete the lines in question but cant figure out how to save the lines from deletion if the line above has the certain phrase

```
$data = foreach($line in get-content C:\e.g\test.txt){ 
  if($line -like "*Example*"){

  }
  else{
    $line
  }
}

$data |set-content C:\e.g\test.txt -force
```

This deletes the lines i need deleted but will also delete the lines i need to save.

```
$data = foreach($line in get-content C:\e.g\test.txt){ 
  if($line -like "*Example*" -and previous line -like "*Phrase"*){

  }
  else{
    $line
  }
}

$data |set-content C:\e.g\test.txt -force
```

Looking for something like the above on how to specify the previous line section

Thanks for any help/solutions anybody has for this.

Comment: Use `$previous_line` instead `previous line` in the latter code snippet (and maintain the `$previous_line` variable properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$previous = $null
$data = foreach ($line in Get-Content C:\e.g\test.txt) {
    if ($line -notlike "*Example*" -or $previous -notlike "*Phrase*") {
        $line
    }
    $previous = $line
}
$data | Set-Content C:\e.g\test.txt -force
```

If one of the above conditions are met, then it won't delete the line. Therefore both conditions between the `-or` will need to be false before the line is ignored.

Comment: Thanks, was able to use this to do what was needed.